# The model did not return a loss from the inputs - LabSE error

Tags: nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I want to fine tune LabSE for Question answering using squad dataset. and i got this error:
`ValueError: The model did not return a loss from the inputs, only the following keys: last_hidden_state,pooler_output. For reference, the inputs it received are input_ids,token_type_ids,attention_mask.`

I am trying to fine tune the model using pytorch. I tried to use smaller batch size and i took just 10% of training dataset because i had problems with memory allocation.
If memory allocation problems are gone this error happens.
To be honest i'm stuck with it. Do you have any hints?

I'm trying to use huggingface tutorial, but i want to use other evaluation (i want to do it myself ) so i skipped using evaluation part of dataset.

```
from datasets import load_dataset
raw_datasets = load_dataset("squad", split='train')


from transformers import BertTokenizerFast, BertModel
from transformers import AutoTokenizer


model_checkpoint = "setu4993/LaBSE"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_checkpoint)
model = BertModel.from_pretrained(model_checkpoint)



max_length = 384
stride = 128


def preprocess_training_examples(examples):
    questions = [q.strip() for q in examples["question"]]
    inputs = tokenizer(
        questions,
        examples["context"],
        max_length=max_length,
        truncation="only_second",
        stride=stride,
        return_overflowing_tokens=True,
        return_offsets_mapping=True,
        padding="max_length",
    )

    offset_mapping = inputs.pop("offset_mapping")
    sample_map = inputs.pop("overflow_to_sample_mapping")
    answers = examples["answers"]
    start_positions = []
    end_positions = []

    for i, offset in enumerate(offset_mapping):
        sample_idx = sample_map[i]
        answer = answers[sample_idx]
        start_char = answer["answer_start"][0]
        end_char = answer["answer_start"][0] + len(answer["text"][0])
        sequence_ids = inputs.sequence_ids(i)

        # Find the start and end of the context
        idx = 0
        while sequence_ids[idx] != 1:
            idx += 1
        context_start = idx
        while sequence_ids[idx] == 1:
            idx += 1
        context_end = idx - 1

        # If the answer is not fully inside the context, label is (0, 0)
        if offset[context_start][0] > start_char or offset[context_end][1] < end_char:
            start_positions.append(0)
            end_positions.append(0)
        else:
            # Otherwise it's the start and end token positions
            idx = context_start
            while idx <= context_end and offset[idx][0] <= start_char:
                idx += 1
            start_positions.append(idx - 1)

            idx = context_end
            while idx >= context_start and offset[idx][1] >= end_char:
                idx -= 1
            end_positions.append(idx + 1)

    inputs["start_positions"] = start_positions
    inputs["end_positions"] = end_positions
    return inputs


train_dataset = raw_datasets.map(
    preprocess_training_examples,
    batched=True,
    remove_columns=raw_datasets.column_names,
)
len(raw_datasets), len(train_dataset)

from transformers import TrainingArguments

args = TrainingArguments(
    "bert-finetuned-squad",
    save_strategy="epoch",
    learning_rate=2e-5,
    num_train_epochs=3,
    weight_decay=0.01,
)

from transformers import Trainer

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=args,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
)
trainer.train()
```

Comment: Instead of `BertModel`,  use `BertForQuestionAnswering`. For the future, please always post the full error stacktrace.

Answer (score 9):

**Hi**,

Please make sure you are good with the below :

- You may need to pass the **label_names** argument in **TrainingArguments** with the label column or key which you are providing, **else** you need to know what is the **default forward argument** which is accepted by the model of your choice

**For example** : with **BertForQuestionAnswering** model, at [huggingface github](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/7d9a33fb5cf40a87ff7fa9b4b8556b9bd4760461/src/transformers/models/bert/modeling_bert.py#L1813)
we can see we need **start_positions** and **end_positions** as key/column_name, which is what gets accepted by model during forward pass.

- Also, from the same link, you need to verify what is the **shape** required by your **labels/target(s)** at **Trainer** **(** this can be different from the logits shape **)**, and provide the one as per link.

Let me know if you or someone is able to resolve the error with the mentioned fix!

**Thanks!**

Comment: This is really helpful info.  Where would I find the default forward argument for models such as salesforce-codegen, starcoder and decicoder?  I'm getting the same error as OP using codegen and suspect it's because the labels are wrong.  Can't find the docs.

Answer (score 2):

Rename columns to text and labels for text classification using distilbert-base-uncased model. It needs to be checked for other domains and models too.

Comment: This worked, can you please explain why ? How are we supposed to know ? Where is this documented ? `label` not `labels`

Comment: Check Also this docs, for the distilbert-base-uncased model, but it works for every transformers . https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.35.2/en/model_doc/distilbert#transformers.DistilBertForSequenceClassification.forward