# ValueError: The model did not return a loss from the inputs, only the following keys: logits,past_key_values

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface

I'm using Pytorch to do huggingface model finetuning with transformers library. I have torch version `'1.13.0+cu117'` with python 3.7.8 and CUDA 11.8. But with some copying and pastinng of others' code, I'm getting `ValueError: The model did not return a loss from the inputs, only the following keys: logits,past_key_values. For reference, the inputs it received are input_ids,token_type_ids,attention_mask.`. I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73290491/the-model-did-not-return-a-loss-from-the-inputs-labse-error) but as a text generation task, I cannot find a proper function like GPT2+text generation so I used AutoModel+Casual LM.

The traceback info is like this:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_8240\3982389964.py in <module>
     47 )
     48 
---> 49 trainer.train()

c:\users\fchen\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\transformers\trainer.py in train(self, resume_from_checkpoint, trial, ignore_keys_for_eval, **kwargs)
   1503             resume_from_checkpoint=resume_from_checkpoint,
   1504             trial=trial,
-> 1505             ignore_keys_for_eval=ignore_keys_for_eval,
   1506         )
   1507 

c:\users\fchen\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\transformers\trainer.py in _inner_training_loop(self, batch_size, args, resume_from_checkpoint, trial, ignore_keys_for_eval)
   1747                         tr_loss_step = self.training_step(model, inputs)
   1748                 else:
-> 1749                     tr_loss_step = self.training_step(model, inputs)
   1750 
   1751                 if (

c:\users\fchen\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\transformers\trainer.py in training_step(self, model, inputs)
   2506 
   2507         with self.compute_loss_context_manager():
-> 2508             loss = self.compute_loss(model, inputs)
   2509 
   2510         if self.args.n_gpu > 1:

c:\users\fchen\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\transformers\trainer.py in compute_loss(self, model, inputs, return_outputs)
   2552             if isinstance(outputs, dict) and "loss" not in outputs:
   2553                 raise ValueError(
-> 2554                     "The model did not return a loss from the inputs, only the following keys: "
   2555                     f"{','.join(outputs.keys())}. For reference, the inputs it received are {','.join(inputs.keys())}."
   2556                 )

ValueError: The model did not return a loss from the inputs, only the following keys: logits,past_key_values. For reference, the inputs it received are input_ids,token_type_ids,attention_mask.
```

The entire code is like this. The `train.csv` and `test.csv` has only lines of sentences in natural language. One sentence per line.

```
from transformers import TrainingArguments, Trainer
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM
from transformers import TrainingArguments
from datasets import load_dataset
import evaluate

MAX_LEN=100

def tokenize_function(examples):
    return tokenizer(examples["sentences"], padding='max_length', truncation=True,max_length=MAX_LEN)

pretrained = "./models/gpt2-chinese-cluecorpussmall/"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(pretrained)
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(pretrained)

data_files = {"train": "train.csv", "test": "test.csv"}
dataset = load_dataset("csv", data_files=data_files)

tokenized_datasets = dataset.map(tokenize_function, batched=True)

train_dataset = tokenized_datasets["train"].shuffle(seed=42)
eval_dataset = tokenized_datasets["test"].shuffle(seed=42)

training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir='./test_trainer',
    num_train_epochs=1,
    per_device_train_batch_size=2,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=2,
    learning_rate= 5e-05,
    warmup_steps=500,
    weight_decay=0.01,
    logging_dir='./logs',
    load_best_model_at_end=True,
    logging_steps=400,         
    save_steps=400,            
    evaluation_strategy="steps",
    report_to=None
)

training_args = TrainingArguments(output_dir="test_trainer", evaluation_strategy="epoch")

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    eval_dataset =eval_dataset 
)

trainer.train()
```